# Realizar 'Check' de uma DataTable (IDs) em lote no banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

Tenho uma pequena aplicação desktop (Windows Forms - .NET 2.0 - C#) no qual eu apenas a utilizo para realizar uma verificação em um determinado caminho de hora em hora e, caso esta verificação encontre algum arquivo .txt neste caminho, é realizada uma importação deste arquivo.

Porém este arquivo possui uma coluna com um ID específico e o que eu faço hoje, é linha a linha checar se esse ID existe no banco de dados. Se sim, ignora, se não importa.

O que eu gostaria de ter uma ajuda é se há alguma forma de eu fazer isso em lote? Sem um "loop" linha-a-linha. Algo que eu enviasse pro banco essa lista de IDs e ele realizasse um "IN" e me retornasse quais não foram encontrados, e ai sim realizar a inserção (bulk insert).

Comment: Você pode adicionar o trecho de código da verificação da id que você utiliza atualmente ?

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma stored procedure com um parâmetro de table, enviando assim uma datatable com os ids e fazendo a lógica dentro da stored procedure. Adicione os trechos de código pertinentes na questão que podemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: @stringNome para qual fim? ^~

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Fiz exatamente isso quando publiquei o post aqui e ficou sensacional! Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada foi criar um TYPE com uma estrutura de TABLE e, posteriormente, uma STORED PROCEDURE que checa no IN se os dados enviados pelo .NET existem no banco de dados. O retorno foi sensacional. Consegui reduzir o tempo de ~40min. para ~3min., um total de 13 arquivos e mais de 100.000 de registros.